# Does a MAX485 need decoupling capacitors?

Tags: capacitor, driver, rs485, decoupling-capacitor

I am designing a small device with two MAX485 chips.

[image]

Do they need the decoupling capacitors on the 5V power?

Comment: This really depends on the impedance and inductance of your supply to the chip; a decoupling capacitor is generally best practice, generally has low cost/complexity for assembly, and shouldn't hurt.

Comment: As a general rule ALL IC's should have ample decoupling capacitors.

Comment: The bypass cap are almost universally used with the purpose of minimising  the power supply impedance.

Comment: Sometimes you can share decoupling caps if you know the feed inductance (e.g. 10nH/cm * length * 2), current rise time  and tolerance for LdI/dt=V drop

Comment: Ask yourself, "What do I know that the manufacturer doesn't?"

Comment: What are the 1K resistors on A1 and B1 and VCC & GND for? Datasheet only calls for 120ohm resistors between A & B. Building something similar and have no clue.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes. All almost ICs need decoupling capacitors. Devices such as these '485 drivers especially need them due to the current surges the device experiences when switching the signal states due to the low value termination resistors used on the bus lines.

Comment: You could debate whether _all_ ICs strictly need decoupling caps, but it never hurts to add some.

Comment: @Hearth this was my question. If it does not hurt